# Laravel 9 found illuminate/contracts but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-9

I have a blank Laravel 9 install. The only extensions added are jetstream and livewire. I am trying to install spatie/laravel-comments package, but I get the following error.

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-comments ^0.0.2 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-comments[0.0.2].
> - spatie/laravel-comments 0.0.2 requires illuminate/contracts ^8.73 -> found illuminate/contracts[v8.73.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these
> were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require spatie/laravel-comments:*" to
> figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require
> spatie/laravel-comments:^2.1" if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

The same error occurs if I specify a version to install or leave it open for latest. I have tried removing the composer.lock file and reinstalling everything, my composer.json looks like.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.11",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.8",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.10"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Versions I'm using are:

composer -v = 2.4

php -v 8.1.3

and I'm on Windows

Answer (score 5):

I've faced this issue once, and i think you need to run this command only

```
composer update
```

Hope this will fix.

and for Spatie installation you can find everything here [SPATIE Installation](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/installation-laravel)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I was trying to install laravel sanctum and it was requiring me to upgrade the iluminate console.

 Problem 1
    - laravel/sanctum[v3.0.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^9.21 -> found illuminate/console[v9.21.0, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/sanctum ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/sanctum[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, 3.x-dev].

After updating composer, it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [package's packagist overview](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-comments), the package is not compatible with Laravel 9. But that is not the largest problem of that package: it is no longer available on Github, so downloading the code might fail.

You should use any other package that suits your needs, or contact the maintainers. Maybe Spatie will re-publish it, and make it compatible with Laravel 9?

Answer (score 0):

[image: php.ini]

I experienced this, when I tried to run composer update, the problem remained the same, but I tried to read the error log carefully, there was an explanation that said the sodium extension was not loaded or was not given access, open extension access in the php.ini configuration file, then I went straight there, omitting the ";" (as a sign called comment) on the line that says ;sodium, and the result worked, I hope this is useful for those who experience the same problem as me.